# Get Contact ip when using viber

Tags: ip, viber

is there any way to found the ip address of a Contact when is online and is chatting with me?
I use desktop viber, and the contacts may use android or desktop version.
i think this maybe unreasonable but i want to know!

Comment: i use wireshark also,but only it detects the server of viber .

Answer (score 0):

**currports.exe** 
like nslookup,but with some possibilies.

*p.s.*
Old versions of skype i used to trace udp packets of videochat of the person. 
Since viber maybe using UDP packets try same "formula"